# How can I fix "Editor placeholder in source file"?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

```
struct CircleView: View {
    var imageName: String

    init(_ imageName: String) {
        self.imageName = imageName
    }
    var body: some View {
        Image(imageName)
        .resizable()
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
        .clipShape(Circle())
        .overlay(
            Circle().stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 3))
        .shadow(radius: 10)
    }
}

struct CircleView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CircleView()
    }
}
```

**The problem is in this part:**

```
struct CircleView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CircleView()
    }
}
```

**XCode suggests:**

*Missing argument for parameter #1 in call*

*Insert '<#String#>'* (into CircleView(<#String#>))

**After I do that:**

*"Editor placeholder in source file"* appears.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Struct `CircleView` has following initializer:

```
init(_ imageName: String) {
    self.imageName = imageName
}
```

So, you have to provide `imageName` of type `String` while creating new CircleView struct.

```
CircleView("myImage")
```

You can always check for all available initializers and their parameter names after pointing carriage into the `()` and clicking `Esc` button
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Give the expected type, in this case, a `String` that corresponds to the parameter `imageName` in the `CircleView` initialization.

```
struct CircleView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CircleView("MyImageName")
    }
}
```